# Implement infinite long running service in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a list of URLs in DB. I want to periodically check if those URLs are alive or not.

So I create a long running service which run infinite loop, each iteration:

- Query database to get list of urls
- For each URL, make request to check if it is alive or not

Please guide me how to implement that service.

I looked at [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) and [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue), but they seem not support infinite loop service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something very simple like [setInterval()](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) to have your task repeat x amount of times.

```
var testUrls = function(){
    //do your magic of connecting to the DB and checking urls.
}

setInterval(testUrls, 60000);
```

The above code snippet will call your function `testUrls` every minute.

Or if you need more control over the scheduling you can use a npm package like [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)

Its very simple

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```